# How to get user information from ldap?

Tags: java, ldap, shiro

I am using apache shiro for ldap authentification:

```
Factory<SecurityManager> ldapFactory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:active.ini");
SecurityManager sManager = ldapFactory.getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(sManager);

Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("user", "password");
            try {
                currentUser.login(token);
            } catch (UnknownAccountException ex) {
                logger.info("Unknown user");
            } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ex) {
                logger.info("Incorrect credentials");
            } catch (LockedAccountException ex) {
                logger.info("Account is Locked");
            } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                logger.info("Authentication Exception");
            }
        }

        logger.info("User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal() +"] logged succesfully");
        currentUser.logout();
```

Calling `currentUser.getPrincipal()`, I've got only email address from the logged user.
How to get more user information, for example lastname, firstname, etc?

Answer (score 1):

`getPrincipal()` only returns the subject's identifier. Try to use `getPrincipals()` instead.

> **Object getPrincipal()**
>   Returns this Subject's application-wide uniquely identifying
>   principal, or null if this Subject is anonymous.
>
> **PrincipalCollection getPrincipals()**
>   Returns this Subject's principals
>   (identifying attributes) in the form of a PrincipalCollection or null
>   if this Subject is anonymous

[Apache Shiro API (JavaDoc)](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.html)

Comment: I already tried it and I've got the same as `getPrincipal()`. I did iterate over `getPrincipals()` but the result is the same as `getPrincipal()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the LDAP Realm. and add more context to Principal/PrincipalCollection (or return a custom object or your Principal)

This is an [old thread](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/How-to-set-a-custom-principal-object-td1090270.html), but I find myself digging it up every once and a while and covers this topic (It mentions JSecurity which is the original project name for Shiro).